# Progress Bar for ftp downloading

Tags: android, ftp, progress-bar, download

Is there anyway to display a progress while downloading a file from ftp in order to show the download progress status ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has documented this part very well, look at it here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

Comment: Ok, thank you. For the ones who are interesting about the subject, there are more informations in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130099/android-displaying-a-progress-bar-while-downloading-a-file