# Android - Displaying a progress bar while downloading a file

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I need some help. I have been searching for days trying to find solution to my problem. I would like to show a progress bar while downloading a file in Android. I found enough to download the file but have struggled to figure out how to display a progress bar.

Here is my download code:

```
            String sURL = getString(R.string.DOWNLOAD_URL) + getString(R.string.DATABASE_FILE_NAME);
        HttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sURL);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Header[] clHeaders = response.getHeaders("Content-Length");
        Header header = clHeaders[0];
        int totalSize = Integer.parseInt(header.getValue());
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            int numBytesRead;

            BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            do {
                numBytesRead = stream.read(buf);
                if (numBytesRead > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, numBytesRead);
                    downloadedSize += numBytesRead;
                    //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
                }
            } while (numBytesRead > 0);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            stream.close();
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: You have to do the downloading in a separate thread. Or else, your code will stuck the main UI Thread which hangs the whole screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an asynctask. There are dozens of tutorials online for exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at AsyncTask but how to I show the progress dialog and update it... based on my code?

Comment: Zarah's answer points you in the right direction. There is plenty of documentation about exactly how to start, update, and dismiss a progress dialog in an asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the [documentation for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?  The example there is **exactly** what you are trying to do. The example uses the method `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`.

Set up a progress bar on `OnPreExecute()`, call `publishProgress()` periodically, and update the progress bar in `onProgressUpdate()`.