# How to set the progress of a ProgressBar for an HttpClient.execute(HttpGet)?

Tags: android, progress-bar, http-get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Displaying a progress bar while downloading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130099/android-displaying-a-progress-bar-while-downloading-a-file)

I do some http get request with HttpGet and HttpClient. What should I call as the parameter for ProgressBar.setProgress() so that a user can get some indication as to how much of the request has completed?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you may want to look at the answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4130099/924 and use an asyncTask to do this.